# Java - efficient form of "OR" in "IF statement"

Tags: java, if-statement

```
boolean a = false, b = true, c = true;
if ( a == false || 
     b == false || 
     c == false ) { return true; }
```

Is there any efficient way of coding for this statement using `:` or `?` symbols or any other *tricks* that you can recommend?

Comment: `return a == false || b== false || c == false.`

Comment: @ArnavBorborah - that is not equivalent to the OP's code.  Look at it carefully.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any efficient way of coding for this statement using : or ? symbols or any other tricks that you can recommend?

There is no efficiency concern here.  What you have written will (most likely) compile to the most optimal native code possible (in Java).

The real concerns here are readability and fragility.

### Readability

Compare these two ways of expressing this

```
if (a == false || b == false || c == false) {
    // Do something.
}
```

versus

```
if (!a || !b || !c) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Now this is a matter of opinion ... but I think that the second form is more readable, and I think most experienced Java programmers would agree with that.

### Fragility

Question: what happens if I accidentally write this?

```
if (a == false || b = false || c == false) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer: an OBSCURE bug!

The `boolean` type is the one type where the compiler will not / cannot tell me that using `=` instead of `==` is a mistake.

But this problem only arises when you use `==` on `boolean` operands.  And in most cases you **don't need to do that**.

Answer (score 5):

I guess a good way with less code could be:

```
if ( !(a && b && c) ) { return true; }
```

Answer (score 1):

A further simplification of @lucasmonteiro001's answer:

```
return !(a && b && c);
```

Ternary operator (although, as mentioned in the comments, this is verbose):

```
return (!(a && b && c)) ? true : false;
```

As pointed out by @StephenC, this could not apply for your question (or it could, you weren't specific enough). So for you, the code at simplest form would either be:

```
if (!(a && b && c)) return true;
```

*OR*

```
if (!a || !b || !c) return true;
```

You may have noticed here that I eliminated the braces, but since you (probably) have more code, you should still have them: aka this:

```
if (!(a && b && c)) {return true;}
```

*OR*

```
if (!a || !b || !c) {return true};
```

Comment: There is no need to use the ternary operator here.  It only serves to obfuscate.

Comment: BTW - this is strictly incorrect.  The original example does not "return" in the else case.

Comment: it would only return true, if the condition was true? So why is it wrong?

Comment: In the original version, nothing happens if the condition is false.  In your version, it also returns false if the condition is false.  Can't you see the difference?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah The OP's code returns true if `a`, `b`, and `c` aren't all true.  If they are, it then checks to see whether there are any files on the disk that contain the phrase "Green eggs and ham", and returns true if there are.  Or maybe it does something else.  We can't tell, since we can't see what code follows.  But we know _something_ must follow, because otherwise Java would refuse to compile the method.